# No usable version of libssl was found on Apple Silicon M1 Mac

Tags: .net, .net-core, openssl, apple-silicon

Code in Azure function breaks locally on M1 Mac when AesGCM does Decrypt

This is the part of the code that breaks

```
using var cipher = new AesGcm(key);
cipher.Decrypt(nonce, toDecrypt, tag, decryptedData, associatedData);
```

I have installed openssl and set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH in ~/.zshrc

Originally the code broke on Intel Mac as well but since I set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, it worked. Yet it still breaks on arm-based M1 Mac.

Configuration

- netcoreapp3.1
- OS Version: Mac OS Big Sur Version 11.4, (Apple M1), 16 GB
- Architecture: arm
- openssl version: LibreSSL 2.8.3, openssl@1.1

Can anyone help please? This seems to be the only issue that stops me from developing in .NET on M1 Mac.

Answer (score 1):

With [Kevin](https://github.com/vcsjones)'s help, I managed to [install Intel version of openssl](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/54597).

The trick was to [use iTerm on Resetta 2 and install Intel version of brew](https://www.wisdomgeek.com/development/installing-intel-based-packages-using-homebrew-on-the-m1-mac/) and then to install Intel version of openssl

- Copy iTerm in the Application directory and rename it to iTerm (Intel)
- cmd + i and tick on "open using Resetta"
- On iTerm (Intel), install brew. It will be installed in `/usr/local`
- `arch -x86_64 /usr/local/bin/brew openssl`
- In `~/.zshrc`, set `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"`

Comment: Hi. I followed this steps but when running unit tests from Rider, still getting same error:

`Exit code is 134 (No usable version of libssl was found)

Last runner error: Process /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet:91708 exited with code '134': No usable version of libssl was found

--- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException]
Message = “
  Process /usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet:91708 exited with code '134':
  No usable version of libssl was found`
In my .zshrc I have export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" 
and installed libs are for x86_64 arch

Comment: installing openssl@1.1 and configuring Env Variable in Rider Unit Test settings helped